# Nullable objects must have value error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've seen this question posted a number of times here but I don't think I understand the solution as it related to my problem.

I'm getting the exception on this line:

```
return CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId == null 
    ? (Guid)CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId 
    : CurrentCompanyID;
```

Here's more of the code:

```
/// Return the current company id, unless this is a child company id, 
/// then return the parent company id.
private Guid MainCompanyID
{
    get
    {
        return CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId == null 
            ? (Guid)CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId 
            : CurrentCompanyID;
    }
}
```

I'm happy to share more if needed but this is about the extent of the stack trace.

Comment: I think you meant `!= null` instead of `== null`.

Comment: Your condition is the wrong way round and should be `!=` instead of `== null`. You could also use the null coalescing operator instead: `return CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId ?? CurrentCompanyID`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `ParentCompanyId` after you've confirmed that it is `null`.
You want to use `CurrentCompanyID` in that case.

This:

```
return CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId == null 
    ? (Guid)CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId : CurrentCompanyID;
```

Should be this:

```
return CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId != null 
    ? (Guid)CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId : CurrentCompanyID;
```

Notice `==` is now `!=`.  You essentially just want to reverse the condition.

Answer (score 1):

You're checking for null and using it. It should be `!=`

```
private Guid MainCompanyID
{
    get
    {
        return CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId != null ? (Guid)CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId : CurrentCompanyID;
    }
}
```

This could be easily re written as the following using null collaescing operator `??` (If parentId is Guid? and CurrentCompanyID is Guid)

```
private Guid MainCompanyID
{
    get
    {
        return CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId ?? CurrentCompanyID;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your `CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId` is nullable, you could also use `null-coalescing operator -??` as below.

```
private Guid MainCompanyID
{
    get
    {
        return (Guid)(CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId ?? CurrentCompanyID);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem in your ternary operator. This line:

```
return CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId == null ? (Guid)CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId : CurrentCompanyID;
```

Basically translates to:

```
if (CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId == null) 
    return (Guid)CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId
else
    return CurrentCompanyID;
```

So the problem is that you are trying to cast a null into a Guid here. You need to reverse your condition:

```
return CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId != null ? (Guid)CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId : CurrentCompanyID;
```

Answer (score 0):

The [? Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) is easiest shortened to:

```
booleanValue ? resultIfTrue : resultIfFalse;
```

Where both the true and false results must by of the same type.

Looking at your code:

```
CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId == null         //booleanValue
        ? (Guid)CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId //resultIfTrue
        : CurrentCompanyID;                    //resultIfFalse
```

This means you are attempting to return the ParentCompanyId when you've already verified it is null.  I'm guessing you wanted to do the opposite.  To do so, You'll want to change your boolean expression to check for not null:

```
CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId != null         //booleanValue
        ? (Guid)CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId //resultIfTrue
        : CurrentCompanyID;                    //resultIfFalse
```

Or, you could leave the boolean expression as is and switch the order of the return values:

```
CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId == null         //booleanValue
        ? CurrentCompanyID                     //resultIfTrue
        : (Guid)CurrentCompany.ParentCompanyId;//resultIfFalse
```

Either should work fine.